# AdMob only works in Xcode canvas

Tags: ios, swiftui, admob, interstitial, ios16

I can’t find the reason why test ads are shown when using Google AdMob in Xcode canvas, but not on the emulator and the phone. In this case, the system does not show a single error.
This happened after switching to iOS16. I use the code similar to this [resource](https://iosexample.com/a-swift-package-that-integrates-admob-ads-into-swiftui/). So I checked all the possible options listed [here](https://support.google.com/admob/thread/228755791/admob-ad-not-show?hl=en). Does anyone have similar problems and how did you solve them?

[image]